# Show that $\frac{d^2E_0}{ds^2} \le 0$ for $\hat{H}(s) \equiv \hat{H}^0 + s\hat{W}$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, energy, perturbation-theory, variational-calculus

> Show that $\frac{d^2E_0}{ds^2} \le 0$ for $\hat{H}(s) \equiv \hat{H}^0 + s\hat{W}$. Additionally, $\hat{W}$ does not depend on $s$ and $E_0(s)$ is non-degenerate.

I'm a little confused on how to approach this problem.

So far I've found that $\langle \hat{H}(s)\rangle$ = $E_0(s) \Rightarrow \langle s\hat{W}\rangle$ = $0$.

From here I'm not sure what to do. For specific cases like $\hat{H} = \frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m}+\frac{kx^2}{2}$ where $s=k$ this problem is easy, but I don't how how to do this for the general case.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that $E_0$ is the ground state energy of your system, including perturbative corrections, that $\hat H^0$ is the unperturbed Hamiltonian and that $s\hat W$ is the perturbation.

Then simple application of perturbation theory gives
$$
E_0(s)=E_0^{(0)}+s\langle 0\vert W\vert 0 \rangle + s^2
\sum_{k\ne 0} \frac{\vert \langle k\vert W\vert 0\rangle\vert^2}{E_0^{(0)}-E_k^{(0)}} \tag{1}
$$
where $\vert k\rangle$ are the unperturbed states and $E_k^{(0)}$ are the unperturbed energies.

The denominator of every term in the $s^2$ part on the right side of (1) is necessarily negative since the ground state energy is smaller than any other unperturbed energy.  The numerator is a modulus square and thus necessarily positive.  Thus 
$$
s^2
\sum_{k\ne 0} \frac{\vert \langle k\vert W\vert 0\rangle\vert^2}{E_0^{(0)}-E_k^{(0)}}  < 0
$$
and the result follows if $\vert \langle k\vert W\vert 0\rangle\vert^2$ does not depend on $s$.